# How to fix " '=' expected near '. .' " error in Lua

Tags: for-loop, lua, concatenation

This error occurs on line 3 of my code and I don't know why.

I'm trying to create multiple variables with x..q, but it doesn't work.

```
for i=1,3 do
  for q=1,3 do
    x..q=i+1
    print(x..q)
  end
end
```

The output should be:
2
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4

But instead it returns the error in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create multiple *global* variables, use code like this:

```
for i=1,3 do
  for q=1,3 do
    _G["x"..q]=i+1
    print(_G["x"..q])
  end
end
```

This code will create globals `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`.

But I think you'd be better off using a table:

```
x={}
for i=1,3 do
  for q=1,3 do
    x[q]=i+1
    print(x[q])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using the operator `..` unintentionally.

When accessing a value of a table, the syntax is `x.q`. [Programming in Lua: 2.5 – Tables](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html)

> To represent records, you use the field name as an index. Lua supports this representation by providing a.name as syntactic sugar for a["name"]. So, we could write the last lines of the previous example in a cleanlier manner as
>
> ```
> a.x = 10                    -- same as a["x"] = 10
> print(a.x)                  -- same as print(a["x"])
> print(a.y)                  -- same as print(a["y"])
> ```

When concatenating a string the syntax is `x .. q`. 
[Programming in Lua: 3.4 – Concatenation](https://www.lua.org/pil/3.4.html)

> Lua denotes the string concatenation operator by ".." (two dots). If any of its operands is a number, Lua converts that number to a string.
>
> ```
> print("Hello " .. "World")  --> Hello World
> print(0 .. 1)               --> 01
> ```